# Excel: Sum the values of corresponding row in next column for colored cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

## Excel: Sum the values of corresponding row in next column for colored cell.

I have 2 columns in my table, and in the 1st column, some cells with values of interest have been colored. In the second column, I have the "costs" for corresponding item in column 1.

The color key is a cell outside the table with same cell color as the other highlighted cells. I want that if the cell color matches with that of color key, then its cost be added to the final sum.

### Example table:

| C1 (Cell colors) | C2 (Values) |
| --- | --- |
| ##### | 78 |
| # | 25 |
| ##### | 17 |
| # | 39 |
| ##### | 5 |
| **Total** | **100** |

`##### cell = green color`

`# cell = no color`

Here, I want the sum of `78`, `17` and `5` in a given cell

Is there a way to do this without filter and sort?

### Machine and S/W info:

- Windows 11 build 22000.434
- Excel 365 version 2112

Comment: The simplest answer to this is NEVER confuse presentation and data. Your use of coloured/non-coloured cells is about presentation, making it easier for you or others to be able to identify differences quickly. However, you are also using colour to represent data (either raw or processed) about the "thing" that represents those differences. Excel was never really intended to allow cell colour to represent data. Sure there are fudges (particularly use of VBA) to get around this, but generally it is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Format Values column as the same as Cell colors column:
   [image]
2. Under Developer tab enter the code:
   Function SumByBGcolor(col As Range, sumrange As Range)

Application.Volatile

Dim icell As Range

SumByBGColor=0

For Each icell In SumRange

If iCell.Interior.Color = Col.Interior.Color Then

SumByBGcolor= SumbyBGColor+Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(iCell)

End If

Next

End Function

[image]
3. Enter the formula:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! it works pretty well: [image](https://i.imgur.com/1qYctZn.png)

Comment: @Lee, a neat solution, and a good example of a user defined function (UDF). Better though if OP hadn't created this problem for her/himself in first place and had used data to represent whatever her/his green/non-green distinction is actually intended to mean. Colour could still be used to present the data and the summations required, possibly using conditional formatting. Excellent animation in your answer.